# Load test of SSL Session ID Resumption

Tags: ssl, loadrunner, grinder

We want to test if we use ssl session id to reuse SSL session, how it will impact on the performance. However we didn't find a way to test it, we use ngrinder or loadrunner to do load test, how to simulate ssl session id resumption in any of the two tools?

Comment: Don't test the platform. It already works.

Comment: @EJP I know it works, but I don't know how much it can improve, if not very much ,I need think about other solution like HTTP. And I also want to know in the server cluster if one server crash, all request will be route to other servers which means all session id is lost, if it will impact lot on server cluster? Appreciate for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In LoadRunner, you can do this by setting the registry key.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mercury Interactive\LoadRunner\Protocols\WPlus\SSL\OpenSSL
```

Try setting the `ReuseSSLSession`'s value to 1.

Comment: Could you please share the document of this config option

Comment: Of cause, we will have a try before accept your answer.